# How does xarray load and index large GeoTIFF files with open_rasterio?

Tags: python-xarray

I'm using the *xarray* package to load and access data of large GeoTIFF files (>50GB) and it is working flawless.

```
import xarray as xr
img = xr.open_rasterio("path/to/large_geo_tiff.tif")
pixel_value = img[0,1225, 4321]
print("The pixel value is: ", pixel_value.values.item())
```

However, I was wondering how *xarray* is actually loading large GeoTIFF files. Obviously it is not loading the whole file into memory since it would not fit but performs some kind of lazy loading. I'm only used to *dask* and *Dask Arrays* which split the data into chunks and allows for easy pixel-access by just loading the corresponding chunk into memory.
But the signature of the function *open_rasterio* looks like the following

`xarray.open_rasterio(filename, parse_coordinates=None, chunks=None, cache=None, lock=None)`

Since I didn't define *chunks* the *img* should not be chunked. So my question is what happens when calling `pixel_value = img[0,1225, 4321]` and how can *xarray* access the pixel value at the given location so fast?

I look forward to any feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like *dask_image* is not so smart at reading *tiff files* in contrast to *xarray*

The provided *GeoTIFF* is not *tiled* but I just checked the *tiff file format* which looks like the following

```
TIFF File: '/Users/jan/Desktop/ms-project/processed/metashape/export/untiled.tif'
                       Mode: 'r'
    Current Image Directory: 1
           Number Of Strips: 1336
                SubFileType: Tiff.SubFileType.Default
                Photometric: Tiff.Photometric.RGB
                ImageLength: 42746
                 ImageWidth: 35366
               RowsPerStrip: 32
              BitsPerSample: 8
                Compression: Tiff.Compression.LZW
               SampleFormat: Tiff.SampleFormat.UInt
            SamplesPerPixel: 3
        PlanarConfiguration: Tiff.PlanarConfiguration.Chunky
                Orientation: Tiff.Orientation.TopLeft
```

the important part is that the *tif* is *[stripped](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/tiff/tiff_summary.pdf)*, where each strip is an individual collection of contiguous row of bitmapped image data which makes random access much easier and *xarray* seems to take advantage of the *stripped* image by just loading the required data - I just checked this by loading the *GeoTIFF* calling the backend module used by *xarray.open_rasterio* called *rasterio*

```
>>> import rasterio
>>> ortho = rasterio.open("./orthomosaic.tif")
>>> ortho.is_tiled
False
>>> ortho.block_shapes
[(32, 248489), (32, 248489), (32, 248489)]
```

*dask_image* on the other hand does not take advantage of those stripes but loads the whole image into one *chunk* therefore running out out memory - even if you write a *tiled* tif file *dask_image* will not consider this

```
>>> import dask_image.imread
>>> ortho = dask_image.imread.imread("./orthomosaic.tif")
>>> ortho
dask.array<from-value, shape=(1, 104700, 248489, 3), dtype=uint8, chunksize=(1, 104700, 248489, 3), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>
```